# PHP + CURL + JOOMLA

Tags: php, curl, joomla

I'm trying login to Joomla 3 from external link via CURL. After some finding from internet I obtain this code with some adaptation:

```
<?php 
$uname = "admin";
$upswd = "admin";
$url = "http://localhost/joomla3/en/component/users";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE );

$results = curl_exec($ch);

preg_match_all("(<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"return\" value=\"(.*)\" />)siU", $results, $matches1);
preg_match_all("(<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"(.*)\" value=\"1\" />(.*)</fieldset>)iU", $results, $matches2);

var_dump($matches1[1][0]);
var_dump($matches2[1][0]);

// POST fields
$postfields = array();
$postfields['lang'] = 'en';
$postfields['option'] = 'com_users';
$postfields['view'] = 'login';
$postfields['task'] = 'user.login';
$postfields['username'] = urlencode($uname);
$postfields['password'] = urlencode($upswd);
$postfields['return'] = urlencode($matches1[1][0]);
$postfields[urlencode($matches2[1][0])] = '1';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
$ret = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($ret);
?>
```

I obtain return & key but cannot login. What is wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: What is the output you obtained ?

Comment: print_r($ret); return nothing (an empty string).

Comment: basics of curl debugging: `curl_error()`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php

Comment: `dirname(__FILE__).'./cookie.txt'` refers to a file never exists (`some_path./cookie.txt`). You have to change it to `dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt'`

Comment: Ah, is my mistake, i have changed this, but result is same.

Comment: I added

`$error = curl_error($ch);
$errno = curl_errno($ch);
echo $error;echo $errno;`

No errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified the code.
Now this work as expected, thanks for support.

```
<?php 
$uname = "admin";
$upswd = "admin";
$url_get_key = "http://localhost/joomla3/index.php?option=com_users&lang=en"; //MOD REWRITE Disabled

//GET return & key
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_get_key );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0 );

$results = curl_exec($ch);

preg_match_all("(<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"return\" value=\"(.*)\" />)siU", $results, $matches1);
preg_match_all("(<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"(.*)\" value=\"1\" />(.*)</fieldset>)iU", $results, $matches2);

//var_dump($matches1[1][0]);
//var_dump($matches2[1][0]);

// POST
$url_post = "http://localhost/joomla3/index.php?option=com_users&task=user.login&lang=en";
$postdata = "username=".urlencode($uname)."&password=".urlencode($upswd)."&return=".urlencode($matches1[1][0])."&".urlencode($matches2[1][0])."=1";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
$results1 = curl_exec($ch);

$url_data = "http://localhost/joomla3/index.php?option=com_users&lang=en"; //MOD REWRITE Disabled
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_data);

$results2 = curl_exec($ch);
$error = curl_error($ch);
$errno = curl_errno($ch);
echo ($error);

curl_close($ch);

//IF incorrect password
if(@preg_match('#<div id="system-message">(.*)<p>(.*)</p>#siU', $results2, $matches3)){
    @preg_match('#<p>(.*)</p>#i', $matches3[0], $matches4);
    echo $matches4[0];
}

//IF Logged In
if(@preg_match('#<div class="login-greeting">(.*)</div>#siU', $results2, $matches5)){
    echo $matches5[1];
}

?>
```